# Padding or Margin to Extend Background Image to Top of Viewport?

Tags: css

I was trying to get my header background image to reach the top of the viewport. There was a gap between the top of my image and the top of the viewport, and I wanted to fix it. I tried applying a margin to my `<header>` css, but this did nothing. What DID end up working was applying padding.

```
 header {
      text-align: center;
      background: url("https://i.imgur.com/E4yIQba.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      color: white;
      padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px;

    }
```

Everything looks good now, but does anyone know why adding 1px of PADDING to the top of the image resolved the issue, while attempting to add a MARGIN of 0px(margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px) did nothing? I thought margins were supposed to move elements closer and farther away from the edges of viewports. I am surprised that padding resolved my issue instead of margin. Thanks!

https://dash.generalassemb.ly/docmp0/build-your-own-blog-theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, **margins are considered to be outside** of the element, and `margin`s of adjacent items will overlap, but on the other hand, **`padding`s are considered to be inside of the element.** So indeed an element's `padding` area is the space between its content and its border when an element `margin` area is a space between that element and elements around it.

So let's see this in an example.

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div.box>div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

div.padding>div {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

div.margin>div {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div>
    <h3>Default</h3>
    <div class="box">
      <div>box A</div>
      <div>box B</div>
      <div>box C</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>padding-top: 1rem;</h3>
    <div class="box padding">
      <div>box A</div>
      <div>box B</div>
      <div>box C</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>margin-top: 1rem;</h3>
    <div class="box margin">
      <div>box A</div>
      <div>box B</div>
      <div>box C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So as you can see in the example adding `padding` to each box will result in growing them in `padding` area, this will work the same for images.

Consider the following image as a content box, whenever you add padding it will apply to the innermost part of a box, and whenever you add margin it will apply to the outermost part of a box.

[image]

**NOTE:** Read more information about [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) and [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

Comment: Thank you @SMAKSS. Padding=inside. Margins=outside. Gottit!